# Create one HTTP Client per API

Tags: c#, asp.net, static

I have a number of classes named `DataAdapter`, located in different folders, each containing a uniquely configured HttpClient to access an external API. I create the right version of the `DataAdapter` class using Reflection.

Cut down example below:

```
internal class DataAdapter : IDataAdapter
{
    public HttpClient Client => GetClient();

    static HttpClient GetClient()
    {
        // This implementation is unique to the API
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.AcceptHeader(MediaType.Json);
        client.AuthorizationHeader("123456");
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);
        return client;

    }
}
```

The premise here is to create one `HttpClient` per API. So when the second user comes along and instantiates a new `DataAdapter` class (in the same folder), they should reuse the same `HttpClient`.

If the user instantiates a `new DataAdapter` class in a different folder, a different version of the `HttpClient` should be created (if it doesn't already exist).

The thing I'm unsure about is the `new HttpClient` in the method - is the example going to return a `new HttpClient` each time a new instance of this exact class is instantiated or is it only ever going to create one?

Comment: The method is static, but `Client` isn't. So every time `DataAdapter` is created each instance will call the static method, creating a new `HttpClient`. Are you by any chance using an `IServiceCollection` and injecting `DataAdapter`? There's a nifty solution for that scenario.

Comment: No, this a custom solution. I'm aware there's some new stuff regarding reuse of HttpClients, but there's a little more to it than is shown in the example.

Comment: You can use dependency injection with a custom solution. Not that I'd necessarily add it just for this. But in that scenario you could do this: `serviceCollection.AddHttpClient<DataAdapter>();` and then inject `HttpClient` into the constructor of `DataAdapter`. Then you set your headers, etc. within your class. The container will manage how the `HttpClient` gets created in such a way that you don't have to deal with it in your class.

Comment: Thanks for the information - I looked at this briefly yesterday. It added around 20 packages to my project which I though was a bit overkill. Still, if a simpler solution doesn't comes along, i'll reconsider it.

Comment: HttpClient can be confusing, make sure to understand these best practices so you are implementing correctly https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shacorn/2016/10/21/best-practices-for-using-httpclient-on-services/

Comment: @str8killinit - thanks for the information, it'll come in handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original code would create a new `HttpClient` every time you accessed the property.  Using the following code would create one the first time it is needed, and then return the same one after that:

```
internal class DataAdapter : IDataAdapter
{
    public HttpClient Client => staticClient.Value;

    static Lazy<HttpClient> staticClient = new Lazy<HttpClient>(()=>
    {
        // This implementation is unique to the API
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.AcceptHeader(MediaType.Json);
        client.AuthorizationHeader("123456");
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);
        return client;    
    });
}
```

The idea is a `Lazy<T>` property gives you a couple of things.  It delays instantiation of the `HttpClient` until it is needed; and, it is gives thread safety without any fuss.  Using a *static* `Lazy<T>` means you get a singleton `HttpClient` per `DataAdapter` class, initialized just in time; which is what it sounds like you are trying to do.

Basically, when you ask for `client.Value`, `Lazy<T>` will create the `HttpClient` using the provided delegate the first time, and remember that value the second time-- all while providing thread safety for you.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, been testing. It does seem to do what I want.